# How to avoid using npx Create-react-app every time

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

Idk but it take too long too settle things ...should i install it globally -g?
It installs react,react-dom too everytime ..if i'd install react globally will it reduce time?

Comment: of course. That will make it easy for you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to increase your chances of receiving a positive response to your query please read and consider the points raised in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a git repository which is a bare CRA app. Whenever starting a new project copy over the files. I particularly like this for typescript projects where I set up ESlint the way I prefer then save it to a project starter repo.